# Squirrelmail change php thread safety to disabled

Tags: thread-safety, pthreads, squirrelmail

While instaling squirrelmail on ubuntu 14.04, php thread-safety change from enabled to disabled (I look in info.php). Because of that, I can't use pthreads which requires thread-safety to be enabled.

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of help you want.  "How do I accommodate SquirrelMail in my server setup?" is more of a question for ServerFault, I think.

Comment: I just want the php thread safety to stay enabled after squirrelmail installing process. But I don't know how to manage that.